# How to properly set up UINavigationController and add views to the stack

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, stack, addsubview

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

self. window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
UINavigationController *navVC = [UINavigationController new];
UIStoryboard *mStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"your storyboard name" bundle:nil];

ViewController *VC1 = [mStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC"];


[navVC setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:VC1] animated:NO];
[self. window setRootViewController:navVC];

[self. window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
  }
```

Now this creates a navigationController but when i try to display the secondViewController it does display me the correct Navigation Bar for that view but i see a black background instead of the actual view. Adding secondViewController as a subview works but when i now try to display the third one it does again display me the correct navigation bar with the set title for this view but i still see the secondViewController's view. Now my question how do I add viewController to the navigationController so they are displayed right? do i even have to add them? I've read through the apple class reference but there isn't any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
self. window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
UIStoryboard *mStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"your storyboard name" bundle:nil];
ViewController *VC1 = [mStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC"];
UINavigationController *navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:VC1];
[self. window setRootViewController:navVC];
[self. window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

now inside VC1 push the next view controller to your stack with

```
// EDIT:
UIStoryboard *mStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"your storyboard name" bundle:nil];
ViewController *vC2 = [mStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC2"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vC2 animated:YES];
```

Comment: I already do this but when it pushes the view controller it doesn't properly set the view, the navigation bar is correct but the view isn't

Comment: the push is the second step. did you implement exactly my codesample in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions? did you setup all storyboard identifiers for each viewcontroller in your storyboard and use the the same identifier in your code to instantiate them? did you see your first viewController ?

Comment: I did see my firstViewVontroller but my problem is that i don't get to see my second or my third

Comment: how do you instantiate your following vcs? and did you controll the identifiers if they are correct set? see the edit in my answer.

Comment: Oh gosh so obvious. Thanks for the help! Everything works fine now :)